# How can i optimize memory use of this C++ code?

Tags: c++, optimization

It's Memento pattern realization, but i need that this code didn't spend a lot of memory when we are creating Memento of big(really big) CustomVector. Maybe we can even sacrifice runtime. Also, Memento must be valid even if the vector object from which he was taken has already been destroyed or overriding with the = operator and it should be possible to copy objects of Memento class.You can change this code a little.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Memento {

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> memento;

public:
    Memento(const std::vector<int>& target) : memento(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(target)){}
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> GetMemento() const {
        return memento;
    }
    Memento(const Memento& a) { this->memento = a.memento; }
};

class CustomVector {

    std::vector<int> vec;

public:
    void PushBack(int value);
    void PopBack();
    void Set(int index, int value);
    int Get(int index) const;
    const Memento CreateMemento();
    void Restore(const Memento& memento);
};

void CustomVector::PushBack(int value) {
    vec.push_back(value);
}

void CustomVector::PopBack() {
    vec.pop_back();
}

void CustomVector::Set(int index, int value) {
    vec[index] = value;
}

int CustomVector::Get(int index) const {
    return vec[index];
}

const Memento CustomVector::CreateMemento() {
    return Memento(vec);
}

void CustomVector::Restore(const Memento& memento) {
    vec = *memento.GetMemento();
}
```

Comment: `Memento(const Memento& a) { this->memento = a.memento; }` -- This function is unnecessary.  The default version generated by the compiler is perfectly ok.

Comment: There's nothing to optimise here really. You need a copy of the vector, so that memory is always going to be taken. If you are running out, consider saving the content to a file (instead of keeping copy in the memory).

Comment: why use a shared pointer for the member? `Memento::getMemento` could return a (const) reference to the member which can be stored as `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: If you are willing to give up on the pattern and you can register changes in the vector, you could also store a "diff" of sorts (so for every `PushBack` call that happens after "diff" started, you register that you need to perform a `PopBack` to restore change etc.). Depending on the number of changes in single "diff", this could be smaller.

Comment: You may be able to rewrite the code logic with a copy-on-write logic. A `std::shared_ptr` won't do in this case though, since it won't allow you to check reliably, if the owned object is used by another thread. Iirc Qt uses logic like this for `QString`. If there is a high chance of memento instances holding a copy the same data being created, there may be some potential for optimization there too. I guess this problem needs to be analyzed in combination with information about the algorithm/dataset used in your program...

Comment: depending on size of the vector and frequency of modifications vs creating a memento, it might be cheaeper to keep track of the changes. For example consider a 100000 element vector and all that is modified is one element getting pushed, then you only need to remember "1 element got pushed" to restore the state before the modifications

Comment: This Memento is a slightly dressed up copy of your vector. If you need a copy, then you need memory for that copy, this cannot be fixed. You can try not needing a copy, but I cannot tell you how to get there, because I know nothing about your starting point.

Comment: You could implement your own `File Organization` instead of put everything to memory. Ex snapshots of  `object name x` will put in folder `snapshots-x`, Filename of each snapshots  will use `<timestamp>.snap`.  There is file `snapindex` in folder for list all snapshots that relate with `object  x`.